# Using RenderAction to bring foreign key ID views together

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that uses SQL Server 2014 as its database. The database has two tables that have a foreign key connection we'll call `form_ID`. I am using the ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application that creates "Index, Delete, Details" views.

I have two controllers that have similar setups ("form", "Comments") where a user can connect their comments (through the create view on the comments controller) to a specific form via dropdown menu using this foreign key. This is how I currently have the tables connected.

What I am trying to do is when a user goes to the details page of a "form" it will display all the form details and any additional comments that were added.

Below is how I tried to implement this.

```
    <div>
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Details", "Comments", new { id = Model.form_ID }); }
    </div>
```

This did merge comments and form details view together but it did not follow the foreign key connection. The `RenderAction` function simply merged the first row of comments and form together.

Is there a better approach to creating a details page that bring the form information and possibly multiple comments in one view based on what the `form_ID` is?

I am fairly new to using ASP.NET MVC and intricacies so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume `Comments/Details/someId` is to show a specific comment details. Should you not be calling the action method which returns a list of comments for the passed in id (form id) ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is possible but what you should do is load the comments together with the form and display them in the same view. If the view is shared with some other place use RenderPartial to render a partial view and pass a view model for the comment rather than the ID.

Comment: @Shyju do you mean something along the lines of creating an 'ActionResult' in the form controller under details that will display specific comment details?  I was looking into doing something along these lines but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Stilgar I was initially trying to do something along these lines. The issue that I ran across with this is comments table contains more than just a single comments section.  There are multiple fields that range between string and int types so I was unable to use RenderPartial since it only allows string types if I am correct. The other issue I had was trying to match the comments to the form where you could have multiple comments matching to the same form using the foreign key ID and displaying all those comments in a single view.

Comment: @final_ace this is not true. The string argument of the RenderPartial method is the name of the partial view. There is an argument of type object where you can pass whatever model you like
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29

Comment: @Stilgar you are absolutely right on this not being true.  Definitely my mistake on misinterpreting some information I read about RenderPartial earlier.  I had trouble trying to load the comments together with the form.  There can be up to 50 comments sections for one form with the form_ID column on both the (Primary Key) form table and (Foreign Key)comments table connecting them together.  Creating a view for each form that would display data based on the form_ID is the goal.  So one form could contain 7 comment sections based on the form_ID while another could have 30 comment sections.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Put a list of comment sections, put it in the view model, make a partial view to display a single section, in the form view loop through the items in the section list and call RenderPartial (Partial is better than RenderPartial but pretty much the same) and you are done (if I understand correctly what you are trying to do)